# Quartz clustering not working

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have my application under Jboss (database is informix) using quartz for scheduling purpose. 
When I have quartz running on 2 clustered Jboss server, I see the jobs are firing on both the servers (few milliseconds apart) for the same fire time.

Any pointers on what can be tweaked such that quartz can run correctly on clustered servers would be of great help.

Thanks for your time and feedback.

Below is how my quartz.properties look like:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MYQuartzScheduler 
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO 

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5 

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX 
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate 
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS 
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = quartz_ 
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false 
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000 
org.quartz.jobStore.maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime = 20 

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.jndiURL= xyzTX 

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true 
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000 

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.JobInitializationPlugin 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames=abc_jobs.xml 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.overWriteExistingJobs = true 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution!

I disabled job file's auto scanning by doing this:

```
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 0
```

and now clustering is working very fine for me.

The `JobInitializationPlugin` will still create jobs from the xml file when the scheduler is started first but will not scan for any changes afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You are running Quartz on JBoss so consider using HASingleton to control master node - then you don't need to use clustering provided by Quartz, which uses database and cause problems.

HASingleton is available since JBoss 4 or 5. If you're using version 7 then you can look at [this post](http://www.kubrynski.com/2013/07/using-ha-singleton-in-jboss-7.html) for details about its implementation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But looks like they wanted to use quartz instead.

Comment: Please -  don't do this :-) We've tried and hit the wall by synchronizing on db

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quartz service definition from my project. All jobs are described in quartz-jobs.xml which trigger EJBs using EJB3Invoker. I hope it helps.

**quartz-service.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server> 
    <mbean code="org.quartz.ee.jmx.jboss.QuartzService" name="user:service=QuartzService,name=QuartzService">
        <depends>jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=myDS</depends> 
        <attribute name="JndiName">Quartz</attribute> 
        <attribute name="Properties">        
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false 
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false 
org.quartz.scheduler.xaTransacted = false 
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool  
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =    org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL = SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS WHERE LOCK_NAME = ? FOR UPDATE
org.quartz.jobStore.txIsolationLevelSerializable = false

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.jndiURL = java:myDS

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.JobInitializationPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileName = quartz-jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.overWriteExistingJobs = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 600
        </attribute>     
    </mbean> 
</server>
```